# Delphi+SQL form is blinking while scrolling

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables related by ID on MS SQL. Delphi-interface looks like 2 DBGrids. By selecting one record from the top table, the bottom table shows all the records with this ID. DBGrid is connected to a stored procedure (TMSStoredProc) that simply displays all records with a given ID. Top table AfterScroll event:

```
Bottom_table_SP.ParamByName('@ID').AsInteger := Top_table_SP.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
Bottom_table_SP.Active := False;
Bottom_table_SP.Active := True;
```

Everything's very simple, and it works. But while I scroll fast top table, the whole form starts to blink - size of top-table and bottom-table changes in the millisecond. Does anyone know how to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're showing tables in master-detail relationship in a more complicated way. Take a look at [`How to create master-detail relationships`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships) for datasets. But it's just a note, it doesn't explain why your form flicker. That's strange and without a detailed code unanswerable from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention SQL Server, I'm guessing you're using the ADO components (`TADOStoredProcedure`) here, so the normal `MasterFields` and `MasterSource` properties aren't available. You still have the basic functionality for other things, so you should use [`TDataSet.DisableControls`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.DisableControls) and `EnableControls` to avoid this flickering:

```
Bottom_table_SP.DisableControls;
try
  Bottom_table_SP.Active := False;
  Bottom_table_SP.ParamByName('@ID').AsInteger := Top_table_SP.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
  Bottom_table_SP.Active := True;
finally
  Bottom_table_SP.EnableControls;
end;
```

You might find [Disabling and Enabling Data Display](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Disabling_and_Enabling_Data_Display) useful to explain.

Comment: It doesn`t help. I put a time-counter GetTickCount, it shows the same results: 0 or 15-16 milliseconds for each next scroll. This time not depends on: certain record; is there try-finally or not; is there DisableControls-EnableControls or not...

Comment: Then there's something else going on in your code. I've used `Disable/EnableControls` in Delphi DB applications since Delphi 1, with databases ranging from Paradox and DBF all the way up to Oracle and SQL Server, and have never had the issue you're having here. I don't have any other ideas without some more information.

Comment: Now I'm going to ask my mentor about this issue because it was a task for homework. Anyway, thank you for your help!